# Python - update database

Tags: python, sqlite

How would I update an entry that is already in a database using sqlite3?

I've tried:

```
db_curs.execute("INSERT INTO `database` (cID) VALUES ('Updated')")
```

But this, of course, creates a new entry. I can obtain the (line(?)) number (of the entry) and what is the command to update the database rather than create a new entry?

EDIT:

Put a bit better, when I convert the SQL entry to a python list I get the following,

```
(1, u'GGS-04', u'John', u'Smith', 9, u'0')
```

I need to be able to add a digit to the last item. Here is what I have.

```
info = (1, u'GGS-04', u'John', u'Smith', 9, u'0')

for result in info:
    ln           = str(result[0])
    ggs          = str(result[1])
    first_name   = str(result[2])
    last_name    = str(result[3])
    dob          = str(result[4])
    spend        = str(result[5])
while True:
    res = raw_input("Enter points to add: ")
    try:
        int(res)
        break
    except:
        print "Please enter a number..."
        pass
spend = str(int(spend) + int(res))
db_curs.execute("UPDATE `" + db_name + "` (cID, first_name, last_name, date_of_birth, spend) VALUES ('" + srce + "', '" + first_name + "', '" + last_name + "', '" + dob + "' WHERE '" + spend + "')")
db_connection.commit()
```

Could someone please explain the correct syntax for this command? It would be awesome if I could just update the "Spend" column than having to update them all from prefixed variables.
Thank you :)

Comment: Your table only has one column? Why are you setting its value to `'Updated'`?

Comment: Use an SQL `UPDATE` statement. I recommend an SQL tutorial if that wasn't obvious to you.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a shot with an 'update' statement. And no, it has multiple columns, I was just giving an example of what I tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This shall work:

```
db_curs.execute("UPDATE database SET spend =`" + spend + "` WHERE cID="+ cID)
```

See also [SQL Update Syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp)

Btw, "database" isn't a useful name for a database's table. What about "users" or "spendtime" or sth more descriptive?

Comment: Thank you, that worked spot on! And thanks for the tip as well. I'm changing it to 'customers' Thank you! :)